# loop using python in html

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

so i want to loop a html element like this(i loop it in a .html file not .py file):

```
{% for i in range(0, row['star']) %}       
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

but it gives me this error :

> TypeError: an integer is required

i know i need an integer for looping but i dont know how to convert it

Comment: So, what is `row['star']`? Is it an integer?

Comment: @DanielRoseman row['star'] is a value from sqlite its a varchar

Comment: So what are you expecting the range to do? How can you have a range from 0 to a letter?

Comment: @DanielRoseman can u tell me how to convert it to integer?that's what im asking,how to convert the row['star'] from varchar to integer

Comment: Okay why do you want to convert to integer ?

Comment: Erm, call `int()`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman tried it,didn't work as well it cause another error like this: UndefinedError: 'int' is undefined

Comment: @RajaSimon so i can loop the html element

Comment: @KelvinSutanto `range(0, row['star']|int)` ?

Comment: @RajaSimon thanks bro it works,you're the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting string to int use `int` template tag

```
{% for i in range(0, row['star']|int) %}       
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star"></span>
{% endfor %}
```